# How to deserve listing all data during the loading page in Javascript - Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I use DataTables Jquery in my page but there is a problem. When I refresh the page It shows me all data to finish the loading page. And after **paging: true** is working

How do I deserve it?

My Datatables code clock:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on( 'shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        $.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust();
    } );

    $('table.table').DataTable({
    "order": [
      [0, "desc"]
    ],
    paging: true,
    "oLanguage": {
      "sUrl": "js/dil/Turkish.json",
    }
    } );

    // Apply a search to the second table for the demo
    $('#myTable2').DataTable();
} );
```

**paging: true is working after loading**